# Google Maps Controls panel size is displayed wrong

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have a weird problem with Google Maps Control.

I've tested in a blank page my custom maps with custom markers and everything seems to be ok, also with the control panel.

When I tried to import all my code in the page I'm working with ( I use a full screen fluid grid system ) the control panel is displayed with strange size.

I tried everything for disable/enable the ui of the Google Maps but the problem remain.

The code of my maps are exactly the same, both in my blank page and in my site, but in the site the ui control panel is displayed very strange.

Here's the code:

```
    <div id="map_canvas2" style="height: 580px; width: 100%;"></div>
        <script>
           var image = 'path/to/your/image.png';
           var mapOptions = {
           zoom: 17,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.499290, 12.621510), 
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           scrollwheel: false
           }
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions);
           var myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(45.499290,12.621510); 
           var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myPos, map: map, icon:           'http://www.factory42.it/jtaca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pin-map.png' });
       </script>
    </div>
```

Here's an img:
http://www.factory42.it/jtaca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/img-maps.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a global rule on images style that is applied on your page 
Are you including the same .css files ? 
Is your page accessible online? Otherwise, you can inspect your image yourself from your favorite console debugger and see what styles are applied on it 
 You can try removing them one by one to detect your problem

Comment: The max-height of the imgs was the problem. You rock!!